# Recyclerview each row timertask handle

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having recyclerview in that each row. I am updating one text value every second, but problem is how I can attach this to each row.

Now I am doing timer task but when I scroll:

1st 4 row only updating for 1sec and rest of other should but now every row is updating how can I stop this?

What is the best way to update text of row every second ?

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run() { , 0, 1000)};
```

Timer task or handle ?

Comment: if you want to update a value that will be eventually viewed by recyclerview. you should just try updating your data list or adapter. views will eventually be recycled in recyclerview so there is no point in attaching any update threads to them

Comment: with this it will update full row i am just updating one text . say each row have 5 types of elements and i want to update 1  text onyl

Comment: simply updating adapter and calling notifyItem/sChanged() is the easy way. otherwise the only way I can think of is getting the LayoutManager and finding if the item you want to update is in view, then getting a reference and updating the part you need. though I've never tried doing it.